# Unable to send email in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send email from website which has the fields name,email,category,subject and message using C# ASP.NET.my requirement is when user clicks on the send button the email will send to the given mail address.I am explaining my code below.

Contact.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" class="contactformdetils" runat="server" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="input">
                <label>Your name:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" name="name" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label>Your email:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" name="email"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="input">
                <label>Category:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory" runat="server" name="category"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label>Subject:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" name="subject"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>Message:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" name="message" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="clearfix captcha">
        <asp:Button  runat="server" Text="Send Message" class="button" id="email_submit" onClick="email_submit_Click"  />
            <div class="captcha-wrapper">
            <asp:Label  ID="lblResult" runat="server" Visible="false" />
            </div> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Contact.aspx.cs:

```
protected void email_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text == "")
    {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Name field should not keep blank";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
    if (txtEmail.Text == "")
    {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Email field should not keep blank";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
    if (txtCategory.Text == "")
    {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Catagory field should not keep blank";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
    if (txtSubject.Text == "")
    {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Subject field should not keep blank";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
    if (txtMessage.Text == "")
    {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Message field should not keep blank";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
   bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), @"\A(?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)\Z");
   if (!isEmail)
   {
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Enter Valid Email ID..";
        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
   }
   if (txtName.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtEmail.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtCategory.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtSubject.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtMessage.Text.Trim().Length > 0 )
   {
       SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
       MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
       try
       {
           MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, txtName.Text);
           smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
           smtpClient.Port = 25;
           message.From = fromAddress;
           message.To.Add("*********@gmail.com");
           message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
           message.IsBodyHtml = false;
           message.Body = txtMessage.Text;
           smtpClient.Send(message);
           lblResult.Visible = true;
           lblResult.Text = "Email successfully sent.";
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           lblResult.Visible = true;
           lblResult.Text = "Send Email Failed.<br>" + ex.Message;
       }
   }
}
```

When a user clicks on the send button the mail shall be send to the email address typed on this form.

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Are you facing any issue with this code? Can you add the exception details here?

Comment: @ Rajeev : Yes,it is throwing Send Email Failed.Failure sending mail.

Comment: Which SMTP server you are using to send mail

Comment: Do you definitely have an SMTP server listening on port 25 of the computer that is running on?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the port number. I had a similar issue once. Try using port

587 or 465

```
smtpClient.Port = 587;
```

or

```
smtpClient.Port = 465;
```

It should work fine.
Try other port numbers if they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
            SmtpClient smtpClient= new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");                
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: @ Musakkir : In this requirement how user can give the credential.Check the view page,It says when user will fill the form and clicked the email will send to the destination address.

Comment: Without credential you can not send an Email. You need to specify email and password. You can do it with code behind or using web.config. But in this case you can use gmail credential of your company or organization if you are making website for them.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

```
smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
smtpClient.Port = 25;
```

**Replace with below :**

```
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
```

**Edit**

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

**Update**

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("From EmailID","Password");
```

**Note :**

`From EmailID` is not `User enterd emailid`. `From EmailID` email which use to send email to end user. And provide that emailid password.

And make sure if your try send bulk mail, then also check `smtpClient.Port` should not block.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: @ smoother : After adding your line it gave me the error like The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. qp10sm2266492pbc.88 - gsmtp.

Comment: @satya i edited my ans... Please add `EnableSsl` in your code

Comment: @ smoother: after editing now error is The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: @ smoother : but here it is throwing error which i have explained above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82703/discussion-between-smoother-sillent-and-satya).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Gmail` to send mail then use

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

instead of

```
smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
```

Comment: Don't forget to downgrade the security level of your gmail sender account, in order to accept smtp mail